# SPARK SQL not in or NOT EXISTS

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a scenario where there are two sheets(csv). Created two tables for it. 
When there s a good data I could map it with a value( id statistic value) from the second table. If I have bad data I should map it with id statistic value again (but a different value). however, I'm unable to use not exists in spark SQL. And I get the error below:

mismatched input 'from' expecting {, 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'INTERSECT', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE'}(line 1, pos 386)

```
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:197)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:45)
```

---

CODE:

```
select
  a.ptf_id,a.ptf_code,a.share_id,a.share_code,a.bench_id,a.bench_code
  , a.l1_calculation_date,a.l1_begin_date,a.l1_end_date,a.l1_running_date
  , a.l1_frequency,a.l1_calculation_step,a.l1_performance_currency
  , a.l1_configuration,a.l1_valuation_source,a.l1_nav_valuation_type
  , a.l1_setting_reference_type, a.l1_setting_valuation_type
  , a.l1_sharpe_ratio_annualized as value,b.id_statistic 
from 
  parquetFile a, 
  pairRDD b, 
  stats c 
where
  a.l1_nav_valuation_type= b.l1_nav_valuation_type 
  and a.l1_valuation_source = b.l1_valuation_source
  and b.l1_Perf = 'l1_sharpe_ratio_annualized' 
  OR (a.ptf_id not EXISTS (
       select e.ptf_id from pairRDD d, parquetFile e 
       where d.l1_valuation_source = e.l1_valuation_source 
       AND d.l1_nav_valuation_type = e.l1_nav_valuation_type) 
  and b.l1_valuation_source ='')
```

this query works in SQL if I use "NOT in"
please help me on what other options to use in this scenario other than not exists.

Comment: One option is to use an outer join; your query is frankly a bit difficult to read but I'd say you should be able to transform it using joins. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The query *is* a bit hard to follow as written.  It's not clear (to me anyway) what your intentions are for the *stats* table since you don't select anything from it so I removed it.  Obviously I haven't tried this myself but at a glance, you might try something like this instead:

```
select
    a.PTF_ID,
    a.PTF_CODE,
    a.SHARE_ID,
    a.SHARE_CODE,
    a.BENCH_ID,
    a.BENCH_CODE,
    a.L1_CALCULATION_DATE,
    a.L1_BEGIN_DATE,
    a.L1_END_DATE,
    a.L1_RUNNING_DATE,
    a.L1_FREQUENCY,
    a.L1_CALCULATION_STEP,
    a.L1_PERFORMANCE_CURRENCY,
    a.L1_CONFIGURATION,
    a.L1_VALUATION_SOURCE,
    a.L1_NAV_VALUATION_TYPE,
    a.L1_SETTING_REFERENCE_TYPE,
    a.L1_SETTING_VALUATION_TYPE,
    a.L1_SHARPE_RATIO_ANNUALIZED as VALUE,
    b.ID_STATISTIC 
from 
    PARQUETFILE a
inner join
    PAIRRDD b
on
    a.L1_NAV_VALUATION_TYPE = b.L1_NAV_VALUATION_TYPE and
    a.L1_VALUATION_SOURCE = b.L1_VALUATION_SOURCE
left outer join (
    select
        e.PTF_ID
    from
        PAIRRDD d
    inner join
        PARQUETFILE e
    on
        d.L1_VALUATION_SOURCE = e.L1_VALUATION_SOURCE AND
        d.L1_NAV_VALUATION_TYPE = e.L1_NAV_VALUATION_TYPE
    where
        b.L1_VALUATION_SOURCE = ''
    ) x
on
    a.PTF_ID = x.PTF_ID
where
    b.L1_PERF = 'l1_sharpe_ratio_annualized' or
    x.PTF_ID is null
```

Comment: Thanks @dgg. It did solve my purpose. And further added some more logic for requirement. If any one faces same issue and needs help. Pls let me know.